Build Error running Tensorflow Lite Android implementation
I have been trying to run the the tensorflow lite android pose estimation quickstart application but the the gradle sync never completes as I run into the following error
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void  org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'
I have tried with different versions of gradle too but no luck
Looks like someone else had the same problem with the digit classifier option in the TFLite quickstart app too with no solution to that either
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62823
Anyone know of a fix to this or is the quickstart project just broken
Would you recommend trying to build it manually from scrtach?
